# Initiate download of Excel Workbook A from hyperlink in Workbook B

Tags: excel, sharepoint, download

Workbooks *Weekly Expenses.xlsx* and *Monitoring.xlsx* are stored on SharePoint.  My team, and I, have CRUD access to these workbooks.  To prevent accidental corruption, the workbooks are exposed in our SP pages as links which initiate a download, without opening in a browser or Excel.  I want to expose the **download link** of *Expenses* within *Monitoring* to reduce clicks for my team.  In my particular situation, a macro is not an option.

Basically, the link is: https://mycompany.com/sites/dept/_docs/Weekly%20Expenses.xlsx?web=0&download=1

The link works for me wherever I place it.  For my teammates it works in Outlook, Teams, and in SP; but, not in Excel.  They receive an error message:  "cannot open the specified file".

Initially, I copied the link from the SP page, created a hyperlink in *Monitoring*, and uploaded *Monitoring* to SP.  When I download *Monitoring*, the *Expenses* download hyperlink in Excel works.  However, the same process and hyperlink fails for teammates.  We have the same group access to all folders and files.  We have tested removing "?web=0" and "&download=1" separately.  Each test resulted in the download working for me but not my teammates.  (I expected the presence of "?web=0" without "&download=1" to NOT download, but it did.)